# How can I execute custom logic after Spring cloud configuration refresh?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have my application set up to use Spring cloud config for providing configuration and have the monitor enabled so that the config server publishes change events to my application. The configuration gets updated correctly, but I want to be notified of when the configuration changes so I can execute some custom logic based on the new config.

I have this configuration object

```
@Configuration
@RefreshScope
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.prefix")
public class MyConfig {
    private Map<String, MyObject> configs;
    private String someValue;

    public Map<String, MyObject> getConfigs(){...}
    public void setConfigs(){...}

    public String getSomeValue(){...}
    public void setSomeValue(){...}
}
...
public class MyObject {
   private String field1;

   public String getField1() {...}
   public void setField1() {...}
}
```

And this in my config servers application.yml

```
my:
  prefix:
    configs:
      TEST:
        field1: "testValue"
    someValue: "test"
```

Now when I change someValue in the configuration, and the config server publishes a refresh, it calls setSomeValue() and updates the value to the new value.  I can add my custom logic to setSomeValue() and it will work fine.  However it does not seem to call setConfigs() or setField1() when updating or adding/removing entries from configs.

I tried registering a listener for EnviornmentChangeEvents, RefreshEvents, or RefreshScopeRefreshedEvents but those are either triggered before Spring updates the values or aren't triggered at all.  I also tried adding logic to @PreDestroy and @PostConstruct methods but only the PreDestroy ends up being called and it's called before the configuration is updated.  I also tried implementing InitializingBean and putting my logic in afterPropertiesSet() but it never get's called either.

How can I get notified when this configuration get's updated?

Answer (score 5):

With a RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent Listener you can get notified when the configuration is updated.

The following example works for me:

The configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    @RefreshScope
    public A aBean() {
        return new A();
    }

    @Bean
    public RefreshScopeRefreshedListener remoteApplicationEventListener(A aBean) {
        return new RefreshScopeRefreshedListener(aBean);
    }

}
```

And the listener:

```
public class RefreshScopeRefreshedListener implements ApplicationListener<RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent> {
    private A aBean;

    public RefreshScopeRefreshedListener(A abean) {
        this.aBean = abean;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent event) {
        System.out.println(aBean.getValue());

    }

}
```

It always print the new value of the configuration.

If you already tried this listener, are you sure that is has been registered well? The bean has been created correctly?

Comment: This surely will work however it will always trigger that method even for other property changes, I think what's missing in RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent is the getKeys() method that EnvironmentChangeEvent can provide however EnvironmentChangeEvent doesn't guarantee the beans with @Refreshscope is updated

Answer (score 0):

What I've done is to get hook of `EnvironmentChangeEvent` listener, and then get the updated properties from the `Environment` itself, not from the `@Autowired Bean bean`

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;

@EventListener(EnvironmentChangeEvent.class)
public void onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentChangeEvent environmentChangeEvent) {
    log.info("Received an environment changed event for keys {}", environmentChangeEvent.getKeys());
    if(environmentChangeEvent.getKeys().contains("key.i.wanted.to.recalculate")) {
        String newValue = env.getProperty("key.i.wanted.to.recalculate");
        System.out.println("New Value: " + newValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can add @PostConstruct with @ConfigurationProperties so that you can write your custom logic

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "dummy.just.to.trigger.actuator.refresh")
Class AnyPropLoader {
@PostConstruct
private void customLogicMethod(){
...
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Create a Bean (dto or an object)
- update it, in any method
- Autowire that dto/object in another class
- That class is updating the values of that DTO/Object

This is how I solved this updating of data and using @Autowired.